# Using Coroutine Flow in Swift

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native, kotlin-flow

How can we currently collect *Flow* from swift?

With the new [Support for Kotlin’s suspending functions in Swift](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew14.html#support-for-kotlins-suspending-functions-in-swift-and-objective-c) flow's `collect` method gets this rather unwieldy signature in swift

```swift
vm.topStoriesFlow.collect(
 collector: Kotlinx_coroutines_coreFlowCollector,
 completionHandler: @escaping (KotlinUnit?, Error?) -> Void
)
```

Any idea how it might be used or even if its usage is currently supported?

Comment: This is an opinion and not an answer.

The support for suspend functions is kind of odd. You can't really control the dispatcher or lifecycle. In general, I'd still write a wrapper for general suspend functions rather than use the built-in, and even more so for Flow, you'd want to write something specific to what you're doing.

https://dev.to/touchlab/kotlin-1-4-suspend-functions-209

In simpler cases, I think the suspend function output makes sense, but in "real app" scenarios, I think you'd want more control.

Answer (score 6):

As Kevin stated one possible and popular approach would be to create a wrapper. You can check out [kotlinconf-app/CFlow](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlinconf-app/blob/master/common/src/mobileMain/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlinconf/FlowUtils.kt) for more info.